# Debezium connect retry (kafka degraded connection)

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I have some occasional problems with some Debezium connections.

Sometimes, people from another team at my company need to do some kind of maintenance on the source database, which I have a Debezium connection pointed to.

And sometimes they restart that source database, which causes the connection to be in "Degraded" status. And every time I need to lift this connection manually, which causes some events to be delayed.

Kafka-Connect log output:

```
[2023-03-15 22:29:11,436] ERROR [lancamentos|task-0] Producer failure (io.debezium.pipeline.ErrorHandler:35)
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: terminating connection due to administrator command
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2675)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2365)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:355)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:490)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:408)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:167)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:119)
    at io.debezium.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareQuery(JdbcConnection.java:709)
    at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresStreamingChangeEventSource.probeConnectionIfNeeded(PostgresStreamingChangeEventSource.java:349)
    at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresStreamingChangeEventSource.processMessages(PostgresStreamingChangeEventSource.java:292)
    at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresStreamingChangeEventSource.execute(PostgresStreamingChangeEventSource.java:177)
    at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresStreamingChangeEventSource.execute(PostgresStreamingChangeEventSource.java:41)
    at io.debezium.pipeline.ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.streamEvents(ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.java:174)
    at io.debezium.pipeline.ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.executeChangeEventSources(ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.java:141)
    at io.debezium.pipeline.ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.lambda$start$0(ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.java:109)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
[2023-03-15 22:29:11,471] INFO [lancamentos|task-0] Connection gracefully closed (io.debezium.jdbc.JdbcConnection:962)
[2023-03-15 22:29:11,472] INFO [lancamentos|task-0] Connection gracefully closed (io.debezium.jdbc.JdbcConnection:962)
[2023-03-15 22:29:11,472] INFO [lancamentos|task-0] Finished streaming (io.debezium.pipeline.ChangeEventSourceCoordinator:175)
[2023-03-15 22:29:11,472] INFO [lancamentos|task-0] Connected metrics set to 'false' (io.debezium.pipeline.ChangeEventSourceCoordinator:236)
[2023-03-15 22:29:11,786] WARN [lancamentos|task-0] Going to restart connector after 10 sec. after a retriable exception (io.debezium.connector.common.BaseSourceTask:240)
[2023-03-15 22:29:11,786] WARN [lancamentos|task-0] WorkerSourceTask{id=lancamentos-0} failed to poll records from SourceTask. Will retry operation. (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:291)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.RetriableException: An exception occurred in the change event producer. This connector will be restarted.
    at io.debezium.pipeline.ErrorHandler.setProducerThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:46)
    at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresStreamingChangeEventSource.execute(PostgresStreamingChangeEventSource.java:180)
    at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresStreamingChangeEventSource.execute(PostgresStreamingChangeEventSource.java:41)
    at io.debezium.pipeline.ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.streamEvents(ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.java:174)
    at io.debezium.pipeline.ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.executeChangeEventSources(ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.java:141)
    at io.debezium.pipeline.ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.lambda$start$0(ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.java:109)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: terminating connection due to administrator command
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2675)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2365)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:355)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:490)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:408)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:167)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:119)
    at io.debezium.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareQuery(JdbcConnection.java:709)
    at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresStreamingChangeEventSource.probeConnectionIfNeeded(PostgresStreamingChangeEventSource.java:349)
    at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresStreamingChangeEventSource.processMessages(PostgresStreamingChangeEventSource.java:292)
    at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresStreamingChangeEventSource.execute(PostgresStreamingChangeEventSource.java:177)
    ... 9 more
[2023-03-15 22:29:11,787] INFO [lancamentos|task-0] Awaiting end of restart backoff period after a retriable error (io.debezium.connector.common.BaseSourceTask:216)
[2023-03-15 22:29:13,787] INFO [lancamentos|task-0] Awaiting end of restart backoff period after a retriable error (io.debezium.connector.common.BaseSourceTask:216)
```

Is there any configuration I can do to have this connection try to reconnect automatically?

Comment: Take a look at "retriable.restart.connector.wait.ms"
https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/connectors/postgresql.html#postgresql-property-retriable-restart-connector-wait-ms
This will extend the time. I don't know yet how to extend the max tries.
Hope this will help. I'm dealing with the same problem. :)